# Unable to find web elements after loading frame with same name

Tags: ruby, ajax, watir-webdriver

I have a little specific question with the following code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require "watir-webdriver"

webpage = "http://www.portalinmobiliario.com/catalogo/fichas.asp?ProyectoID=4308&tp=1&op=1&iug=306&ca=1&ts=1&mn=2&or=&sf=1&sp=1"
pag_detalle = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
pag_detalle.goto(webpage)

if pag_detalle.frame(:id => 'iFrameFicha').table(:id => 'TableInformacionBasicaProyecto').exists? then

    pag_detalle.frame(:id => 'iFrameFicha').table(:id => 'TableInformacionBasicaProyecto').link(:id => 'btnCotizar').when_present.click

    sleep 5

    if pag_detalle.frame(:id => 'iFrameFicha').table(:id => 'Cotizar').exists? then
        puts "existe"
    end

    pag_detalle.close       
end
```

The code opens firefox and loads a page. Then click on 'Cotizar' button. After that, the frame 'iFrameFicha' change its content but can`t access to its elements.

The error message indicates that I should switch to the container frame but I am not able to.

Answer (score 1):

The error message you are seeing seems like a bug in watir-webdriver (or selenium-webdriver). From a quick test, it appears that exception is thrown whenever trying to access anything within a frame *and* the element does not exist. I believe this is the same as [Issue 211](https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/issues/211). The exception in the issue is different, I believe, only because it is using Chrome (ie if you use firefox for the issue, you get the exception you do).

In particular, when you do the line:

```
if pag_detalle.frame(:id => 'iFrameFicha').table(:id => 'Cotizar').exists? then
```

The element does not exist, which (incorrectly) throws an exception as mentioned above.

When I looked at the page, there are 3 tables, none of which have an id.

I am guessing you actually want the table with the *class* "Cotizar":

```
<table class="Cotizar" border="0" width="100%">
```

Which would mean the code should be:

```
if pag_detalle.frame(:id => 'iFrameFicha').table(:class=> 'Cotizar').exists? then
```

But maybe you want the body element has the id "cotizar" (note the lower case).

```
<body onload="resize();ExisteMarco();" style="margin:0px;" id="cotizar" class="pageBtn">
```

In which case you would need to do:

```
if pag_detalle.frame(:id => 'iFrameFicha').body(:id => 'cotizar').exists? then
```